# scrapy recursive crawler does not follow link

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am completely new to scrapy and am trying to scrape data from a website that consists of a very simple html table. The data is structured in several pages with 500 observations per page, with two links "Previous 500 entries" and "Next 500 entries" at the bottom of each page (those are the only links). I want the crawler to click on "Next 500 entries" until there are none left. Extracting the first page works fine but I cannot get the crawler to move to the next page.
My code is probably quite a mess since it is what I picked together from several online tutorials, apologies for that. From my limited understanding of how the programme should work, I cannot find the mistake. Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from test.items import testitem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.example.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/data"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=("//a[contains(text(),'Next 500 entries')]/@href")), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath("//table/tr")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = testitem()
            item["var1"] = titles.select("td[1]/text()").extract()
            item["var2"] = titles.select("td[2]/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: where is the `parse_items` method?

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot! just had to replace "def parse(..." with def parse_item(...". However, now I am getting an error message that says: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter'"

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out :-) Just had to delete the @href from the restrict_xpaths and it started crawling just like it should. Thank you!